# cursor.getString returns null with a valid uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap

All of a sudden the program has stopped working.

I have a URI: "`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A13`", a file path to an image.

The path for the URI is chosen like so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,  data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                // This bit here
                Bitmap bitmap = getPath(data.getData());
                Log.i("Bitmap", "Bmp: " + data.getData());

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", "Error with setting the image.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, `getPath()` is called, putting the data in as a URI (URI is correct, the log shows that)

In `getPath()`:

```
private Bitmap getPath(Uri uri) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // it is this line here, it returns null for some reason.
        String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

        // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.

        Log.i("File Path", "File name: " + filePath); // this comes out as NULL in the logcat

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

        filePathForUpload = filePath;

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", "error with bitmap!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Logcat output:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: filename cannot be null
     at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:121)
     at build.com.build.SubmitPicActivity.getPath(SubmitPicActivity.java:123)
     at build.com.build.SubmitPicActivity.onActivityResult(SubmitPicActivity.java:93)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 123 is : `String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));`

And line 93 is: `Bitmap bitmap = getPath(data.getData());`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `private Bitmap getPath(Uri uri)` Wrong name as it does not return a path but a bitmap. Better let it return filePath. And then make another function Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(String path);. Makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A `Uri` is not necessarily a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). The code that you are using to try to get a `File` for a `Uri` was never reliable and will not work much going forward.

Please consume the `Uri` appropriately, using a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` and `getType()`. In essence, you treat a `Uri` the same way that you would a URL to a Web server, and for much the same reason: there is no requirement for the content surfaced by a `ContentProvider` to be coming from an ordinary `File` that your app can access.

Comment: Thank you for the comment here. My understanding is that the `Uri` is a path to the image location, and the `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);` 'synthesizes' the image? Is that correct?

Comment: @JoshBoothe: "My understanding is that the Uri is a path to the image location" -- only to the extent that an HTTP URL is "a path to the image location". "and the Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath); 'synthesizes' the image?" -- it decodes it, as the method name suggests. It reads in the PNG or JPEG file and creates a `Bitmap` object from that data. For a `Uri`, use `decodeStream()`, using the `InputStream` that you get from `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: thanks, this was the "aha!" moment for me. Realising that a Uri that is returned has no guarantee to be a File makes sense, and is the reason this is non-trivial.

Comment: Could you guys provide an example instead of "aha" moments?

Comment: @CommonsWare if the content uri came from selecting a file, is there a way to hardcode the content-uri-string (or any other related information) so that after restarting the program I can access is without having to select the file manually again? (this is for development purposes)

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz: If you get the `Uri` via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you can call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to the content. Then, you could save the `Uri` either programmatically (e.g., `SharedPreferences`) or manually (e.g., print it to Logcat and hard-code it in your app for development purposes).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your reply.
I read in [one of your posts](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) that Uri Access Lifetime is only for the duration of the app (and even shorter).  
From your above comment I now understand that if using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, takePersistableUriPermission(), and SharedPreferences than the Uri can sustain an app restart.