# cursor.getString() returning null

Tags: android, uri

I am new to android (started this week) and am currently writing a photo album app for a class. I am currently trying to get an image selected by the user, however, after selecting the image I am using cursor to get the path but the `getString()` method is returning null. Here is the code segment in `onActivityResult`:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(filePathColumn[0]);
final String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
//create photo object
```

I used the debugger tool to step through the code. `data.getData()` does not return null.`filePathColumn[0]` contains `"_data"`,  `crusor.moveToFirst()` returns `true` and `columnIndex = 0`. Then the `cursore.getString(columnIndex)` returns `null`. Can anybody help me figure out what is going wrong ?

Comment: Do you actually have a `MediaStore` URI? How did you get your URI?

Comment: More importantly, why do you need the path? There is no requirement for a `Uri` to point to a file that you can access.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need the path to store to later on display the image in an `ImageView`

Comment: @ianhanniballake wouldn't `data.getData()` get me the URI after the user selects a photo from the chooser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cursor.getString returns null with a valid uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171967/cursor-getstring-returns-null-with-a-valid-uri)